# Swift: how to change Edit/Done buttons behaviour/function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbaritem

In my iOS app I have a `UITableViewController` whose rows contain data and data picker. I want to change te function of the buttons Edit and Done. I would like the Edit button to allow the user to write/insert data (instead of deleting rows), while I would like the Done button to save to save the data (and not just exiting the edit mode). I've added to my code the following:

```
// The following two functions remove the red minus sign
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

in order to avoid appearing the circle red minus, but how can I override the functions according to Edit or Done value of the button? I heard about delegates but I'm new to iOS and I don't know what they are...if someone can explain me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code block :-)

```
import UIKit

// You can initialise an instance of this class manually or configure it on storyboard
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    // MARK:- This part is for demo purpose
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    // MARK:- From here is the main part to answer your question
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
            print("Write/Insert data here")
        }

        let doneAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Done") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
            print("Save data here")
        }
        doneAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        return [doneAction, editAction]
    }
}
```

You will see the result like this
[image]

Comment: Thank you, very useful and clear...I will adapt it to my case.